# Short code mouseenter & mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

Write working code, but it's big. How to reduce this code:

```
$('.js_service').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass("js_animated fadeOutLeft");
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("fadeOutLeft").addClass("fadeInLeft");
  })
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('span').removeClass("fadeInLeft").addClass("fadeOutLeft");
  });
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, and 9 lines can't really be considered "big" ?

Comment: no need for 2 `mouseenter` handlers. Both add same class `fadeOutLeft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two `mouseenter` handlers:

```
$('.js_service').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('span').addClass("js_animated fadeOutLeft")
                        .removeClass("fadeInLeft");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('span').removeClass("fadeOutLeft").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    })
```

And you can actually roll it into a single handler if you bind it using `hover`:

```
$('.js_service').hover(function(e) {
    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
        $(this).find('span').addClass("js_animated fadeOutLeft")
                            .removeClass("fadeInLeft");
    } else {
        $(this).find('span').removeClass("fadeOutLeft").addClass("fadeInLeft");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could roll this all up into one `hover()` handler .

```
$('.js_service').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass("js_animated fadeOutLeft fadeInLeft") 
});
```

When only one argument provided it will fire for both `mousenter` and `mouseleave` and toggleClass will handle add/remove class.

If you provide 2 handlers as arguments then the first is mouseenter and the second is mouseleave

```
$(selector).hover(function(){
  /* mousenter code */
},function(){
  /* mosueleave code*/
});
```

Reference: **[hover() API docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hover function to have either one function that fires on both events, or two functions. [Here is the documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('.js_service').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('span').addClass("js_animated").toggleClass("fadeOutLeft fadeInLeft");
});
```

This code will make sure you have the js_animated class and will toggle the fadeOutLeft and fadeInLeft. Make sure your spans have one of the classes to begin with otherwise they will both toggle on and off at the same time. In your case I think you want to have the fadeInLeft class on them.